# Display Custom Field for a Specific Role, but not for Admin

Tags: custom-field, user-roles, profiles

How do I display a custom field for a specific role, but not display it on the profile page of the admin? When admin goes to edit a profile user that this role, the field will visible.

I created two fields for Subscriber role, but the fields appears on admin profile page.
I need to display these fields only if admin goes to the profile page of subscribers.

```
function show_custom_field_for_subscriber(){

    if( current_user_can('administrator') || current_user_can('subscriber') ) {

    //code html for display the fields

}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_custom_field_for_subscriber' );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `WP_User` class and the `has_cap($role)` method. The `show_user_profile` action passes a `WP_User` object as a parameter to the called function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#has_cap.28.24cap.29

```
add_action('show_user_profile', 'my_add_extra_profile_fields');
function my_add_extra_profile_fields($user) {
    if ($user->has_cap('subscriber'))
    {
        //Code here
    }
}
```